Adapting default settings of new SSIS packages
In earlier versions of SSIS I could adapt the file Integration Services Project.dtproj to set some defaults for new packages such as protectionlevel and targetserverversion.
However, I do not seem to find this file in SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022? Using File Explorer Pro I only found a mention of  in some dll that I do not know (or am willing) to adapt.
Is there a way to

have a template for the default package.dtsx
to change the default settings for protectionlevel and targertserverversion?

